# Sophos virus protection continuously blocking codegv.ru

Tags: malware

While using google chrome I keep getting a pop-up from Sophos saying "High Risk Website Blocked - Access has been blocked to "codegv.ru"

It happens every time I perform any action in google chrome. Any navigation and it comes up.

I suspect there to be Malware on my computer. I am currently letting Sophos scan my computer.

What should I do if it does not find anything and it keeps happening?

Comment: It is indeed a suspect site. According to [ScanUrl.net](http://scanurl.net/) the site `codegv.ru` has a negative reputation at [Web of Trust(WOT)](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/codegv.ru). And [McAfee SiteAdvisor reports it as a spam URL](https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/codegv.ru). And there are reports about hacked Ukrainian sites having scripts linking to codegv.ru

Answer (score 2):

check your chrome extensions - you might have accidentally installed a malicious extension

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: yes it does provide an answer, he is asking what he should do to get rid of the malware and I suggested he look at his chrome extensions since it makes most sense that if chrome tries to access a suspicious url every time he does something with it, than the malware is just an unwanted chrome extension

Comment: I checked the extensions, nothing unusual. Nothing I don't recognize.

Comment: Sophos is done scanning - didn't find anything. Using Windows 8 btw... :)

Comment: Well that sucks. Malwarebytes did not find anything either.

Comment: Here is what Sophos is blocking:http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/Mal~HTMLGen-A.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you have a proxy defined in chrome? you might want to check that as well

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem and it went away after I removed the following browser extension:

AS Magic Player 1.0.0

As mentioned above, check your extensions thoroughly, even if you trust them try disabling one at a time to figure out which is causing the issue.

Comment: AS Magic Player 1.0.0 does cause this problem but removing it will only be a temporary fix because it will come back! I'm still trying to find a solution